# how to print a specific json key in php?

Tags: php, arrays, json

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include"smsciniz/vendor/autoload.php";
    include"smsciniz/baglan.php";
    
    //$insert =  $DB->query("INSERT INTO sc_ulke(ulke_isim) VALUES(?)", array($_POST["ulke_isim"]));
     
    $ulke =  $DB->query("SELECT * FROM sc_ulke");
    
    foreach ($ulke as $value) {
       $url = file_get_contents("https://5sim.net/v1/guest/products/".trim($value["ulke_isim"])."/any");
       $json = json_decode($url,true);
     
       echo $json;
    }
?>
```

And here is my JSON data:

```
"1688": {
"Category": "activation",
"Qty": 2000,
"Price": 14.83
},
"1xbet": {
"Category": "activation",
"Qty": 11413,
"Price": 19
},
"32red": {
"Category": "activation",
"Qty": 4113,
"Price": 7
},
"888casino": {
"Category": "activation",
"Qty": 4109,
"Price": 5
},
"99app": {
"Category": "activation",
"Qty": 5437,
"Price": 5
},
```

I want to print the area I marked but I don't know how to do.
I would be very happy if you could help me with an example, thank you in advance

```
"32red": {
    "Category": "activation",
    "Qty": 4113,
    "Price": 7
    },
```

Comment: With `print_r()` ?

Comment: `json_decode($url, true)` will return an _array_ representation of the json data. You can't `echo` arrays. When you post code, you should also include what actually happens. In this case, you should get a "Array to string conversion" warning/notice (unless the decode fails for some reason). The posted json data is not valid though (it's incomplete)

Comment: I want to print 32red

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? What **exactly** do you want to print?

Answer (score 1):

We can iterate and find by particular key and print result using [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) with `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`

```
function findObjByKey($res, $keyToFind){
    foreach ($res as $key => $value) {
     if($key == $keyToFind) {
         return $value;
      }
    }
    return NULL;
}

$json = json_decode('
  {"1688": {
  "Category": "activation",
  "Qty": 2000,
  "Price": 14.83
  },
  "1xbet": {
  "Category": "activation",
  "Qty": 11413,
  "Price": 19
  },
  "32red": {
  "Category": "activation",
  "Qty": 4113,
  "Price": 7
  },
  "888casino": {
  "Category": "activation",
  "Qty": 4109,
  "Price": 5
  },
  "99app": {
  "Category": "activation",
  "Qty": 5437,
  "Price": 5
  }}'
);

$res = findObjByKey($json, '32red');
$prittyPrint= json_encode($res, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo "<pre>".$prittyPrint."<pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

use `json_encode($json['32red'])` like this you can access any key in json

Comment: Please share more details. How should this print `32red`, as requested in the comments?